# How to check quality of CD/DVD before burning?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc, burning, dvd-burning

I recently bought a couple of DVDs to burn but majority of them turned as faulty DVDs. I came to know when the DVDs were not able to burn the data into them. Hence Is there a way by which I can check (before actually burning the disc) that whether the blank CD/DVD is not faulty and would burn without any major issue?

I used Windows 7 OS and Nero Express/Burning ROM and/or Img Burn to burn the data into DVDs

Answer (score 1):

You need a 3rd party tool for that as you'll need full control over the burning device. I'd recommend [qpxTool](http://qpxtool.sourceforge.net/) as it's free (sourceforge prj)
Adding this for a better understand...

> What can I do with QPxTool?
>
> With QPxTool you can measure the quality of CDs and DVDs, if your hardware supports these features (supported drives). Further you can take full advantage of the special Plextor writing features (like GigaRec, VariRec, PowerRec, AutoStrategy).

and:

> It is the Open Source Solution which intends to give you access to all available Quality Checks (Q-Checks) on ***written and blank media***, that are available for your drive.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: No.

There's really no way to know that a blank media is any good until you burn it and then attempt to read it afterward.  Ideally in at least 2 different readers to mitigate alignment issues in the burner.

If a disc is particularly horrible, burning in Test Mode may reveal a failure, but it's unlikely.

The safest thing to do is to start with only good quality media.  It's been several years since I've had to do any regular DVD burning, but Taiyo Yuden was generally regarded as being decently priced and consistently high quality.  Verbatim also generally made decent blank single-layer DVDs.

Comment: How I can know that whether my DVD ROM is not working or my DVD has experienced failure? Sometimes the DVD works but sometime the DVD rom works but not DVD.

Comment: The only things you can do are to try to read with multiple devices and use a media scanning tool like the linked to qpxTool to profile the media.  CD/DVD burning is mostly a game of convergence, where you have to find the right combination of devices and media and burning software and settings such that you get discs that can be read more often than not.

Comment: I've had good luck with those two brands myself, burning at slow speeds with good burners. All the other cheap ones I've tried ended up more often than not as coasters, and even if they worked I wouldn't trust them to archive important data anyway. (For that matter even with good quality media it's recommended that you copy to new discs every 4-5 years.)